# iOS App Review: Additional files?

Tags: ios, ssl, app-store, appstore-approval

Is it possible to provide additional files for an AppStore app review?

We are developing an app that communicates with an SAP server. In order to review the app we set up a test server that will be accessible for Apple. But the certificate on that server is self-signed.

We want to include the CA root certificate somewhere in the review, but the only place I can imagine right now is somewhere in the app bundle. But the certificate won't be needed by future users, thus we don't want to include it in the binary.

The obvious solution (using a "real" certificate) has already been discussed and declined (server is just there for the review, will be used once/twice a year => cert cost too high)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a link in **App Review Information → Notes**

[image]

Or just make a note about it and the Apple itself will demand it when the app will be "In Review" phase (file can be attached in the **Resolution Center**).

[image]

Comment: Regarding attaching file in Resolution Center: I have a similar issue at the moment, where we are considering sending a "special binary (app bundle)" to app review. While this might be a bit different from OP's question I am still suspecting a few possibly related problems here. 1: The app review team likely has a rule to never test any other binary than the one sent the normal official way. 2: Even if we sent a binary through Attach File, the app review team might technically be unable to install it to a device. -->

Comment: --> Obviously we can't make an adhoc because we don't know their UDID, and they likely can't use an appstore distribution ipa either. Still this is exactly what I'll be doing from now; I'll send them an appstore distribution ipa and see what happens. Background story is: they asked to be able to play a feature of our game, this feature is only unlocked after playing said game for a while, and while we can't ask them to play for a long time we can give them a "special binary" that unlocks said feature from start.

Comment: @Tron Can I attach video by clicking on "Attach File"

Comment: @Meera I think the type of the file should not be a problem. I'm not sure, if there is some file size limitation.

Comment: @Meera So try to add a link to your video to the notes.

Comment: @Tron I didn't found any attachment in note area.

Comment: @Meera Not as an attachement, just put it on some server (your own, YouTube, Vimeo, ...) as not public video, and give them URL in the note.

Comment: @Torn I thought there is some tap at where I can attach. :p Btw thanks :)